# Filtering condition in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on SSRS 2008 for creating a simple list report. I created a Calculated field which results in two values either New or Renewal for rows.

`=iif (LEFT (Fields!ProductShortName.Value, 5)= "Renew" or
       LEFT (Fields!ProductShortName.Value, 2)= "TR" or 
       LEFT (Fields!ProductShortName.Value, 2)= "XR" or 
       LEFT (Fields!ProductShortName.Value, 3)= "WOW" or 
       LEFT (Fields!ProductShortName.Value, 3)= "Gra" or 
       LEFT (Fields!ProductShortName.Value, 3)= "CTr" ,"Renewal", "New")`

I want to further filter the data by excluding the data where the Value is "Renewal" and MaturityDate is null

For that purpose I created another calculated field:

```
=iif (Fields!New_Renew.Value = "Renewal" and 
      Fields!MaturityDate.Value <> "" or 
      Fields!New_Renew.Value = "New", cdbl(1),cdbl(0))
```

And then filter this field by 1. 
I get a blank report when I run it. Can anyone please suggest an appropriate coding for my requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NULL is not the same as an empty string. NULL is an unknown value thus cannot be evaluated.

Try:

```
=IIF(
    (Fields!New_Renew.Value = "Renewal" AND IsDate(Fields!MaturityDate.Value))
        OR Fields!New_Renew.Value = "New", 
    cdbl(1),
    cdbl(0)
)
```

Comment: I tried doing what you said but I am getting an error saying >'Calculated Field' cannot be converted to 'String'

Comment: Try getting rid of the length comparison

Comment: After doing that, I get records for only 'New'

Comment: Okay that is progress. Are you able to provide sample row data for renewals?

Comment: Try using (Fields!New_Renew.Value = "Renewal" AND IsDate(Fields!MaturityDate.Value))

Comment: I appreciate your effort. That worked. Can you please edit your answer to this. So that I can accept the answer.